# User Authentication with EntityFrameworkCore and MySQL DB not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am developing a .Net Core Web Application using Entity Framework and MySQL and when I try to register as a user, I get the following message.

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Connection must be valid and open to commit transaction
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTransaction.Commit()
```

This is my DB Context

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    }
}
```

}

And this is my Startup code

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();

    }
```

--UPDATE----

I Found out that the Authentication mechanism is done by Ajax not EF, the problem seems to stem from this line of code.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
   PROBLEM LINE====>         var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                _logger.LogInformation(3, "User created a new account with password.");
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }
```

Comment: are you sure you have a valid connection string in appsettings.json for "DefaultConnection"?

Comment: Yes, the connection string works fine. For other data, it actually works fine, its only with the Authentication that it gives such problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having this exact same problem amonst a few others the other night. It's some kind of issue with async and the Oracle MySQL provider. If you override your DbContext's dispose method and put a breakpoint in there, you see the context gets disposed before some of the sign in steps are done. I found another SO question (can't find it right now on mobile), that had similar issues and recommended replacing Oracle MySQL package with this one:

https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql

This fixed the problem and another problem I was having related to handling of varbinary data types longer than 255 when adding migrations.

Also remember the DbContext is loaded into the DI container in the "scoped" lifetime (by default), which means it is a single instance per http request, so make sure your code or any middleware you have in place isn't disposing the DbContext after getting it from the service container.

Comment: YES! Thank you so much. I agree, I think that because its in pre-release, its still buggy. but Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql Library works fine! Thanks!